# Weird spacing in h:panelGrid with h:inputText and rich:comboBox

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am experiencing a *very* strange issue where the space before and after an rich:comboBox 
differs from that for a h:inputText. See the screenshot below. Everything is fine for the datePicker and Application ID. The spacing gets weird for the comboBox. Any ideas? -Jan

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa5qv.jpg

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.lblsearchapplicationId}" />
<h:inputText id="inputapplicationId" value="#{searchBean.searchApplicationCriteria.LNGAPPLICATIONID}" />

<h:outputText value="#{bundle.lblsearchdealerName}" />
<rich:comboBox suggestionValues="#{XXXglobalHelperBean.dealerNames}" directInputSuggestions="true">
    <!-- <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.searchApplicationCriteria.TXTDEALERNAME}" /> -->
</rich:comboBox>

<h:outputText id="lblsearchbusinessManagerName" value="#{bundle.lblsearchbusinessManagerName}" />
<h:inputText id="inputbusinessManagerName" value="#{searchBean.searchApplicationCriteria.TXTBUSINESSMANAGERNAME}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

sooooooooo, I figured it out. There is a rich-combobox-shel around each comboBox. One needs to set margin and padding for this shell to the same values as for h:inputText.

```
.rich-combobox-shell {
    position : relative;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```